# Ubuntu Has No Internet :/

Tags: networking, server, 23.10

**Ubuntu Server 23.10**

My server was working perfectly fine, until one day I woke up to it having no internet.

The server has a static IP address, and I can use it locally, however when I try to run `ping google.com`, it outputs `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`. `ping 8.8.8.8` works.

Comment: Your DNS isn't working correctly. You could try updating the DNS nameserver (could use `1.1.1.1`). Here are some instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/211757/how-do-i-set-a-static-dns-nameserver-address-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: @moo that does not work